# Activity booking database schema advice

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am starting to put together a database to book students on activities for a week. A tutor needs to log in and have access to all students in their tutor group. There are 4 activity slots per day (mon - fri) that the students can pick from. One of these days(different day for each year group(first year of high school is called year 7 in the uk)) will be booked out for a trip so access yo every student for a year group is needed.

I have been prototyping the schema but I'm convinced there is a better way to do it so any help would be appreciated. I have included the proposed schema (not the full data in the tables just the important details  ).

```
staff table
------------------
|ID | STAFF_NAME |


student table
-------------------
|ID |STUDENT_NAME|


activity table
-------------------
| ID |ACTIVITY_NAME|

year group table
--------------------
|ID | YEAR_GROUP_NAME|

day table
---------------------
|ID | DAY_NAME|

session table
--------------------
|ID| SESSION_NAME |

tutor group table
--------------------------------------
|ID |STAFF_ID:FK|STUDENT_ID:FK|YEAR_GROUP_ID:FK|

booking table
---------------------------------
|ID|STUDENT_ID:FK|DAY_ID:FK|SESSION_ID:FK|ACTIVITY_ID:FK
```

Comment: Might be better asked on the sister site, https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is year group? Do you mean the freshmen, sophomore years or dates year? Your entire Question could use some editing for detail and clarity.